# VirtualBox apt source.list sources.list.d. What is the difference?

Tags: apt, virtualbox

On the official website, they say I have to put this line in my source.list

`deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian <mydist> contrib`

and at other websites I saw this, but what is the difference?

`echo 'deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian' $(lsb_release -sc) contrib | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list`

This is the part I don't understand

`| sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list`

What is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run in terminal:

```
echo 'deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian' $(lsb_release -sc) contrib | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
```

It will write the output of `echo 'deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian $(lsb_release -sc) contrib'`  to a file named `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list`

It's working the same as adding:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian <mydist>     
contrib
```

to /etc/sources.list

The diferrens is that the files is located in different places. One to
`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list` and another to `/etc/sources.list`

The contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list` are:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian $(lsb_release -sc) contrib
```

and the contents of `/etc/sources.list` are:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian <mydist> contrib
```

NOTE: replace `<mydist>` with the output of `lsb_release -sc` command

`$(lsb_release -sc)`  = `<mydist>`

Comment: So if i use 

`echo 'deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian' $(lsb_release -sc) contrib | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list`


Then are 

`<mydist> contrib`  missing ?

and sources.list is empty if i use this line ?

`echo 'deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian' $(lsb_release -sc) contrib | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list`